# Select last row before value changes

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in an access db with columns for testseries, sample, result, name, and measurement. For each testseries and name I want to select the last sample and result where measurement is TRUE and all previous results are TRUE.

So, if I have

| FID_testseries | FID_sample | ID_result | Name | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | John | true |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | John | true |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | John | false |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | John | true |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | John | false |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | Jane | true |
| 1 | 2 | 7 | Jane | true |
| 1 | 3 | 8 | Jane | true |
| 1 | 4 | 9 | Jane | false |
| 1 | 5 | 10 | Jane | true |
| 1 | 1 | 11 | Jeff | false |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | Jeff | true |
| 1 | 3 | 13 | Jeff | true |
| 1 | 4 | 14 | Jeff | false |
| 1 | 5 | 15 | Jeff | true |

I want to select

| FID_testseries | FID_sample | ID_result | Name | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | John | true |
| 1 | 3 | 8 | Jane | true |

[Select rows where value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487533/select-rows-where-value-changes) got me pretty close to the result, but I get a result each time the measurement changes from true to false, which is not what i want.

EDIT 22-12-2021:
The abovementioned SQL:

```
SELECT
        qRes.FID_testseries ,
        qRes.FID_sample     ,
        qRes.ID_result      ,
        qRes.name           ,
        qRes.measurement    ,
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 sqRes.measurement
                FROM
                        qryResultater sqRes
                WHERE
                        qRes.name           = sqRes.name
                AND     qRes.FID_testseries = sqRes.FID_testseries
                AND     qRes.FID_sample     < sqRes.FID_sample
                ORDER BY
                        sqRes.FID_sample ) AS nextMeasurement
FROM
        qryResultater AS qRes
WHERE
        ((
                SELECT
                        TOP 1 sqRes.measurement
                FROM
                        qryResultater sqRes
                WHERE
                        qRes.name           = sqRes.name
                AND     qRes.FID_testseries = sqRes.FID_testseries
                AND     qRes.FID_sample     < sqRes.FID_sample
                ORDER BY
                        sqRes.FID_sample)) <> qRes.measurement
AND     qRes.measurement                    = -1;
```

Which returns

| FID_testseries | FID_sample | ID_result | Name | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | John | true |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | John | true |
| 1 | 3 | 8 | Jane | true |
| 1 | 3 | 13 | Jeff | true |

Comment: Edit question to show the attempted SQL.

Comment: @June7 I have updated the question to include the SQL. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT Data.FID_testseries, Data.FID_sample, Data.ID_result, Data.Name, Data.Measurement, 
   DCount("*","Data","Measurement = False AND FID_testseries=" & [FID_testseries] & " AND [Name]='" & [Name] & "' AND ID_result <=" & [ID_result]) AS Cnt
FROM Data
WHERE (((DCount("*","Data","Measurement = False AND FID_testseries=" & [FID_testseries] & " AND [Name]='" & [Name] & "' AND ID_result <=" & [ID_result]))=0));
```

or

```
SELECT Data.FID_testseries, Data.FID_sample, Data.ID_result, Data.Name, Data.Measurement, 
   (SELECT Count("*") FROM Data AS D WHERE Measurement = False AND FID_testseries=Data.[FID_testseries] AND [Name]=Data.[Name] AND ID_result <=Data.[ID_result]) AS Cnt
FROM Data
WHERE ((((SELECT Count("*") FROM Data AS D WHERE Measurement = False AND FID_testseries=Data.[FID_testseries] AND [Name]=Data.[Name] AND ID_result <=Data.[ID_result]))=0));
```

If Measurement is a text field instead of yes/no type, enclose False in quote marks.

Query2:

```
SELECT Query1.* FROM Query1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Max(ID_result) AS IDR, FID_testseries, Name
     FROM Query1 GROUP BY FID_testseries, Name) AS Q 
ON Query1.ID_result = Q.IDR;
```